32bit ODBC driver for MySQL 8.4.0
I have legacy project built for 32bit platform that works with MySQL. It specifically requires 32bit ODBC driver. By now I am using MySQL 8.0.37 which offers 32bit driver. I checked download page: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/ and it shows Windows (x86, 64-bit), MSI Installer for MySQL 8.4.0 . Is there 32bit ODBC driver for MySQL 8.4.0? Is it theoretically possible to use 32bit ODBC driver for MySQL 8.0.37 to access MySQL 8.4.0 server?

Depending on what you are doing, you can 100% use the 8.0.27 32bit ODBC driver to access v8.4.0 server.
By that I mean if there are some new features that don't exist in your older driver those won't work but anything else should work just fine.
